# How to place finger numbers below staff in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

I cannot find out, how to place the finger numbers below the staff of the left hand staff in a piano staff.

The command `\set fingeringOrientation = #'(down)` does not work or it only works with chords.

This is an example:

```
\version "2.19.83"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff a'1-1
    \new Staff \relative c, { 
        \clef bass 
        \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
        c4-5 \tuplet 3/2 { c8-5 f-2 g-1 } \tuplet 3/2 { a-2 g-1 f-2 } c4
    }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: 1]

I'd like to have the finger numbers for the left hand below the staff. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just specify whether you want them up or down for each note, using `^` or `_` instead of `-`.

```
\version "2.19.83"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff a'1-1
    \new Staff \relative c, {
        \clef bass
        c4_5 \tuplet 3/2 { c8_5 f_2 g_1 } \tuplet 3/2 { a_2 g_1 f_2 } c4
    }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to position a larger number of fingerings, you can use `\override Fingering.direction = #-1`:

```
\version "2.19.83"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff a'1-1
    \new Staff \relative c, { 
        \clef bass 
        \override Fingering.direction = #-1
        c4-5 \tuplet 3/2 { c8-5 f-2 g-1 } \tuplet 3/2 { a-2 g-1 f-2 } c4
    }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to notate the fingered notes as single-note chords (`c4-5` becomes `<c-5>4` etc.).

```
\version "2.18.2"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff a'1-1
    \new Staff \relative c, { 
        \clef bass 
        \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
        <c-5>4 \tuplet 3/2 { <c-5>8 <f-2> <g-1> } \tuplet 3/2 { <a-2> <g-1> <f-2> } c4
    }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of OP's music with fingering below the staff as desired.]

While this method is not great in terms of semantics (and requires more effort), it has the benefit of being compatible with `\set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)` or `#'(right)`, which I find are a necessity for polyphonic classical guitar.